# Strike [lightning]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I've recently come across the tag [lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lightning) and I believe it is confusing and unnecessary, and therefore a good candidate for burnination. This tag has 143 questions at present.

Looking at the criteria for burnination:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

There is usage guidance for it:

> Questions about the Lightning extension to Mozilla Thunderbird

However, another tag [thunderbird-lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird-lightning), with 24 questions, also exists, which is clearly for the same topic:

> Lightning brings the Sunbird calendar to the popular email client, Mozilla Thunderbird. Since it's an extension, Lightning is tightly integrated with Thunderbird, allowing it to easily perform email-related calendaring tasks.

The [lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lightning) tag is not unambiguous because there are several other lightning related tags, most notably [salesforce-lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-lightning) with 665 questions.

From a quick sample of the questions, they include

- Some questions that are unclear, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320721/can-we-have-number-value-on-the-top-of-charts-bars), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251999/how-to-implement-client-side-pagination-on-json-response-with-images-urls-in-lig) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708770/is-there-any-function-that-we-can-use-to-compare-the-system-time-and-time-the-li), some of which will Roomba shortly
- At least [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849964/why-the-audiounit-collect-940bytes-per-frame-under-the-earphone-with-lightning-p) about the Lightning connector on the iPhone that needs to be detagged
- At least [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017120/drupal-8-call-to-a-member-function-setrevisionable-on-null) about *acquia/lightning* that should be retagged to [acquia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acquia)
- The majority, however, (at least 37/50 on the first page) are actually about  [salesforce-lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-lightning), e.g.
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61950117/lightning-for-outlook-addin-configuration-is-editable), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430993/adding-a-unique-index-when-duplicate-values-exist-in-the-column) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654496/repeating-salesforce-workflow-actions-every-x-days)

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Quite a lot of the questions actually seem quite low quality, but the concepts (apart from the Lightning connector) are on topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No - it's too widely misused. Many of the questions are double-tagged, e.g. [lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lightning) and [salesforce-lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-lightning), but many are only classified in [lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lightning) which is very unclear.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

As above, no. It could mean at least 3 different things, probably more.

My suggestion:

A brief community effort to correctly tag the majority of the questions to [salesforce-lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-lightning), [thunderbird-lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird-lightning), [acquia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acquia) or [lightningchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lightningchart) as appropriate, followed by the deletion of [lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lightning). I suspect that most of the questions that can't be clearly moved to the correct tag, could probably be closed as needing details or clarity.

Comment: Good target, especially since [tag:lightning] never strikes the same target.

Comment: @10Rep That's a misnomer, for what it's worth.

Comment: @10Rep You've just linked a list of google results backing up what I said.

Comment: There's been plenty of people that have been struck by lightning more than once. It's incredibly unlikely, but not by any means impossible.

Answer (score 15):

143 questions, ambiguous tag.

I am all for immediate disambiguation by editing all of the questions. I only found one question I couldn't immediately identify which tag it should have.

[(plugin Rollup Core) Error: Could not load /Users/Naseem/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/wpe-lightning-cli/src/alias/wpe-lightning.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63391177/plugin-rollup-core-error-could-not-load-users-naseem-appdata-roaming-npm-nod)

The only reason I could find to not just do this immediately is a proper burn effort might be needed to scrub the off-topic lightning questions about using the Thunderbird Lightning extension.

Comment: That's a question about an NPM module for the [Lightning](https://github.com/rdkcentral/Lightning) tv app framework. Not sure what a good alternative tag might be.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has "Lightning" all over the place in the feature names.

- Lightning Experience (UI that replaces the [2010](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages) "classic" version),
- [Lightning Sync](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_sync_admin_overview.htm&type=5) (sync Gmail/Outlook contacts),
- [Lightning Connect](https://developerforce.github.io/lightning-connect-tutorial/index.html) (pulling data from external databases and ETLs using [OData](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data_Protocol))
- Lightning App Builder (drag&drop UI generator)
- Lightning Platform (the whole Platform-as-a-Service thing; question could be about database design, API access, anything really)
- ...

Questions about these are IMO poor fit for SO as most of it is pure config, no code. I rarely close them but some tag guidance that https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ is better fit could help.

Pure coding-related questions could be about lightning-web-components ([lwc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lwc)), Aura components ([aura-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aura-framework), more or less) or [lightning design system](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) (set of CSS rules & guides) for example.

Comment: Are you suggesting that many of the `salesforce-lightning` questions should really be tagged `lwc` instead? I see 56 questions are already tagged with both. They could both do with updating by an SME - the `salesforce-lightning` tag in particular sounds more like marketing than useful SO guidance.

Comment: I've never done mass retag, maybe you could ask what https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/ thinks, there are proper experienced moderators and MVPs :). But looking at newest 3: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63528866/313628 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/63507012/313628 have nothing lightning-ish about them, no UI pieces. no code (could be straight closed as unfit for SO? or tag removed?) https://stackoverflow.com/q/63491596/313628 could be retagged to `lwc`

Comment: I'm not sure the facility exists to ask another stack exchange to lend a hand. It's not an area I'm familiar with, but there would hopefully be other SME's here who could help with retagging/closing the Salesforcey questions.